# AWS Lambda Layer - Version increment despite any code change

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, version, aws-lambda-layers

I am creating lambda layer in my `Cloudformation` template as shown below. The problem is, with each and every deployment, the lambda layer version increments. For example, the current layer version `120` for the `PythonUtilsLayer` shown below. I was under the assumption that, `SAM` will modify a resource only if there is an underlying change (i.e,  something inside `../../utils/py/` here ). Any idea why `SAM` creates a new version eventhough there is no change?

```
  PythonUtilsLayer:
    Type: "AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion"
    Properties:
      LayerName: !Sub "${Stage}-PythonUtilsLayer"
      Description: Utility layer for python functions
      ContentUri: "../../utils/py/"
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.7
        - python3.8
      LicenseInfo: Crowdblink
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: python3.7
```

Comment: You can try setting up [RetentionPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-layerversion.html). Maybe by default it set to `Retain`.

Comment: As per [this](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-manage) from AWS, AWS SAM skips the layer update, in case no changes to your dependencies. So are you sure of this is not happening?

Comment: @Marcin I thought `RetentionPolicy` is for `Delete`s, let me try and see whats the behavior of it on stack updates, (in this case indirectly resource updates; since the layer code does not have any change but the layer version gets updated)

Comment: @amitd That's correct, I haven't changed anything in the layer, since those are a few utility libs, those seldom gets changed between stack updates.

Comment: @JimsonKannantharaJames did you get it resolved?

Comment: Having the same issue, using a makefile maybe that's why?